# Struggling with uint64_t

Tags: c++, uint64

I want to set individual bits in a 64 bit number and figured that the `uint64_t` is ideal for the job. I ran into some strange problems, so I did some experiments:

I wrote the following test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{

    uint64_t test_value = 0;

    for( int i=0; i<63; ++i ) {
        test_value = (1 << i);
        std::cout << hex << test_value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output surprised me:

```
1
2
4
8
10
... (irrelevant output elided)
10000000
20000000
40000000
ffffffff80000000
1
2
4
8
10
...
10000000
20000000
40000000
```

I tested the max value (`std::cout << hex << std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() << std::endl`)
resulting in `ffffffffffffffff` as expected.

I am running gcc 12.2.1 on Fedora 37.

It looks like my unsigned int changed to signed on bit 31 and rolled over on bit 32.
Am I missing a compiler setting?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: std::bitset<64> might help you too : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler should have warned you.
In this line:

```
test_value = (1 << i);
```

`1` is an `int` literal (and `int` is usully 32 bit).

E.g. in MSVC I get:

> warning C4334: '<<': result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64
> bits (was 64-bit shift intended?)

You should change it to:

```
//-------------vvv-------
test_value = (1ull << i);    // You can also use: (uint64_t)1 instead of 1ull
```

And now you'll get the output you expect.

Comment: Of course (face palm). Thank you so much. ul did the trick.

Comment: Oops, ull not ul did the trick.

Comment: Sure. `ul` is for `unsigned long` which is usually still 32 bit. `ull` is `unsigned long long` which is 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing a compiler setting?

I think what you are missing is that `1` is an `int`, and `sizeof(int)` can be less than `sizeof(uint64_t)`.  Shifting a 32-bit value left by more than 31 bits yields results that aren't particularly useful.

If you replace `1` with `1ULL`, or alternatively with `((uint64_t)1)`, you will get behavior that is more in line with your expectations.